# Not getting the desired title in gganimate - animated labels with expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I want to add a unit of `m^2 m^-2` (but as an expression) next to a variable using `gganimate`. For example the following gives me my desired output when I do it using only `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
        geom_point() +
        labs(title = "Hp" ~ m^2 ~ m^-2)
```

However, when I do the following using `gganimate` I do not get a changing value of Hp, but `{closest_state}`

```
library(gganimate)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        transition_states(hp) +
        labs(title = expression('Hp = {closest_state}' ~ m^2 ~ m^-2))
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: When I run your `gganimate` code I get an error `Error: Provided file does not exist`

Comment: @RonakShah can you please check with the updated code? I updated a few things in the  `gganimate` code (the older code still works for me though).

Comment: Do you have to pass the string as `expression` ? What if you pass it as string directly? Something like `labs(title = 'Hp = {closest_state} m²')`

Comment: @RonakShah I would strongly prefer passing it as an expression. Because this is just a simple example, in reality I have to write physical formulas and units. Btw, how did you write `m²` like that directly in R?

Comment: I just found `m²` somewhere on the internet and copy pasted it in R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `ggtext::element_markdown()` which allows a [limited subset of `Markdown` format](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/articles/introduction.html).
This is enough for exponents and indices as in your example, but unfortunately [Latex math isn't yet available](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext/issues/4).

```
library(ggtext)
library(gganimate)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  transition_states(hp) +
  labs(title = "Hp : {closest_state} m^2  m^-2")+
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Comment: very nice. Thanks. See how this bounty goes but you're already on a good position :) - on the other hand, OP still needs to see if this also works with their maybe more complicated expressions.

Comment: @tjebo thanks for you comment. See my edit : unfortunately Latex $math doesn' work yet :-(

Comment: FWIW I've raised an issue / feature request on GitHub https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/439. I have continued trying with all kinds of combinations to come up with a way to correctly parse this to no avail. Curious to hear what the package maintainer says about this.

Comment: @Waldi 's method (using `ggtext`) worked perfectly for some of the units I used. But it does not work when things get slightly complicated. Although I have accepted @Waldi 's answer (because it does solve the specific problem example I have originally posted) I am still looking for other methods that will work for all mathematical expression.